# How to access "this.props" from static react function in redux

Tags: reactjs, static, this, bind

I defined a test function in a react class and this function can callable from another component this why I defined test function as static.

```
class myClass extends Component {

.
.
.

    static testFunction {
        console.log(this.props.testData); // data from redux
    }

  render() {
        .
        .
        .
      }

   const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

       testData: state.myReducer.testData

    }

}
```

and another component calling test function

```
import myClass from './myClass'

console.log(myClass.testFunction())
```

But getting an error message

cannot read property (testData) of undefined

I think the static function is can't access to "this"

what can I do for access "this" from static function

Comment: You cannot access "this" from a static method by principle. This is only available from an instance method of the class. What are you trying to achieve by making the method static?

Comment: @PatrickHund Thanks for answer. method is special method for myClass, has some special codes which coded for myClass and also method must be callable from another class

Comment: @PatrickHund i finally want to a method which is accessable from other components and can access to "this"